# PHP not working with Apache on Centos 7

Tags: php, httpd, centos7

I'm on centos 7 and have the `httpd` service (2.4.6) installed from yum no problems and I had to install PHP from a different repo `remi` to get php 5.6 installed.

PHP works on the command line and the httpd service is running but all php is not being executed, there are no errors in any logs, and the below php.conf exists.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

<IfModule  mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I've been at this hours now going around in circles and just can't seem to see where the disconnect between apache and php is, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happend when you try to display a php page, php source is displayed ?

Comment: @Froggiz, PHP code is displayed plain-text.

Comment: @llanato, create test.php with the following code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and put it in your Apache document root or anywahere that you can execute from a browser. Then see what happens when you go to page http://hostname_or_ip/test.php. This is a test to see if php is working with apache.

Comment: @bangal, as I already said, php isn't working with apache at all, it's only working on the command line and all php code is displayed as plain-text.

Comment: @llanato, what does your `/var/log/httpd/error_log` says when you try to execute a php page?

Comment: @bangal, there are no errors in any logs and no errors on screen

Comment: @llanato, can you make sure the php module for apache is installed and loaded? Try adding `LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so` just before `SetHandler...` line.

Comment: What is the list of RPM installed ?  (rpm -qa php\*) as it seems "mod_php" is not installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your `php module` for apache is not working. It's may be not properly installed or configured.

To see all available modules, you can run:

`apachectl -M`

You can enable the module by adding the following line either in httpd.conf or your vhost config file:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

Answer (score 5):

Every time I have this problem, it is because I did something like:

```
# yum install httpd php-mysql
# yum install php-fpm
# systemctl start httpd
```

Finally I remember that this is not a dependency and get it working:

```
# yum install php
# apachectl -M | grep -i php
 php5_module (shared)

# systemctl enable httpd
# systemctl restart httpd
```

At this point I can use php in httpd without external repos or mod_php package listed in "rpm -qa"

Comment: Why do you say without mod_php package? You installed mod_php and you are using it!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem that mod_php is not default installed after I install PHP and httpd, now it works with this command:

```
yum install mod_php
systemctl restart httpd
```