# Apache php include not working - CentOS7

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php

I've a php application running on Apache. Earlier it was running on CentOS6 Operating system without any issue. Now we have upgraded OS to CentOS7. But application is not working.

Not sure the same php application not working fine on new OS.

After debug this issue, noticed that php "include" options are working.

Should I need to install anything on the new CentOS7 server? . Even I tried on different CentOS7 machine. Same problem.

Someone please help me on this.

Comment: I found similar post where the **PHP Module** for Apache on CentOS7 seems to be not working : http://serverfault.com/questions/738441/php-not-working-with-apache-on-centos-7

Comment: its not php not working issue. its related to "php include" not working. which means, if use include function to call another php, its not working

Comment: If I change the php handler from "AddHandler php5-script .php" to "AddHandler php5-script .php5". Now part of the site content is loading. Still some page are showing php code on the page. 
Code : " 0) { //$s = 0; while($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) { extract($row); // $id=$row['id']; echo $row['content']; } ?>"